# Best alternative to goto's in THIS case (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I was working in VB trying to set a Datagridview's cell background colour and coulnd't find a built in function that let me achieve the functionality so I ended up storing the values of Alpha, Red, Green and Blue in variables and then setting the background colour using `Color.FromArgb'

This is the code I used and it works:

```
             currentval = ""
                        A = ""
                        R = ""
                        G = ""
                        B = ""

                        For Each s As Char In reader.ReadElementString("cell")
                            If s = " " Then
                                currentval = ""
                                GoTo nextSS
                            End If

                            If Not s = "," Then
                                currentval = currentval & s
                            End If
                            If s = "," Then
                                If A = "" Then
                                    A = currentval
                                    currentval = ""
                                    GoTo nextSS
                                End If
                                If Not A = "" And R = "" Then
                                    R = currentval
                                    currentval = ""
                                    GoTo nextSS
                                End If
                                If Not A = "" And Not R = "" And G = "" Then
                                    G = currentval
                                    currentval = ""
                                    GoTo nextSS
                                End If
                            End If
                 nextSS:
                        Next s
                        If Not A = "" And Not R = "" And Not G = "" And B = "" Then
                            B = currentval
                            currentval = ""
                        End If

                        Grid.Rows(i).Cells(y).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(A), CInt(R), CInt(G), CInt(B))
```

I later realized that this is probably not the best way of doing this so I was wondering how would you guys approach and solve this problem? As it says on my profile, I am here to learn and any advice from more experienced developers will be taken into consideration for when I need to tackle similar problems in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the `GoTo` by just using `Else` clauses, but if you want to split a string by a seperator, you should really use the [String.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Say your string is `"166, 244, 100, 0"` then you could use something like:

```
Dim colors = value.Split(","c).Select(Function(v) CInt(v)).ToArray()
Dim new_color = Color.FromArgb(colors(0), colors(1), colors(2), colors(3))
```

- the `Split` method splits the string by `,` into 4 parts
- the `Select` takes each part and converts it into an integer using `CInt`
- the `ToArray` takes the sequence and converts in into an `Int`-Array so we can access the elements with an index
- then we use that array to create the `Color` object with `Color.FromArgb`

Comment: obviously I didn't do enough research before tackling the problem and this would have been much more efficient and less lines of code as well. thank you so much for the advice